# How to disable or stop Bluetooth driver programmatically using C# and WMI?

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth, wmi

How to disable or stop Bluetooth driver programmatically using C# and/or WMI?
I've tried method "Disable" which is in namespace Win32_NetworkAdapter,
but looks like it doesn't help.

here is an example, what I've done:

```
ManagementObject classInstance =
                new ManagementObject("\\root\\cimv2",
                "Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID='16'",
                null);

            // no method in-parameters to define


            // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
            ManagementBaseObject outParams =
                classInstance.InvokeMethod("Disable", null, null);

            // List outParams
            Console.WriteLine("Out parameters:");
            Console.WriteLine("ReturnValue: " + outParams["ReturnValue"]);
```

Thanks for any ideas!

upd: I've also tried to call StopService on WIN32_SystemDriver object, but it returns error code 4;

Comment: What's the purpose? What do you want disabled? What about disabling service "bthsvcs"?

Comment: Bluetooth is really not stable, and a lot of BT bugs can be solved, by removing BT dongle and inserting back; so I want to implement reseting BT programatically.

Comment: @alanjmcf Hi, I've found a solution, but I have a question for you. When I've used any method from 32feet, I can't disable BT, seems like the assembly holds a handle to a hardware. Is it possibly to unload this handler or something like this?

Comment: Yes we don't close the radio handle. Its something I've been meaning to look at. I've just committed a fix. Can you download the library sources use a built version to see if that solves it.  http://32feet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets    http://32feet.codeplex.com/workitem/33017